# What is the `g` in angular selectors for?

Tags: angular

Some [ngx-charts](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/master/src/line-chart/line.component.ts) components have a `g` in the selector like this:

```
selector: 'g[ngx-charts-line]'
```

What is the `g` for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngx-charts` uses [SVGs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) (Scalable Vector Graphics) to create it's charts and components. As a result, the `g` in the selector targets [SVG `<g>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) which are used to group other SVG elements. This selector specifically targets `<g>` elements with the `ngx-charts-line` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

`g` is just the line element's tag name which `ngx-charts` used in a line chart.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it is the HTML `<g>` tag:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g